# Formula returning Column A value for row containing MAX value of a range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Assume I have the following table:

```
  A         B         C
1           Week 1    Week 2
2 Melissa   114.7     82.8
3 Mike      105.5     122.5
4 Andrew    102.3     87.5
5 Rich      105.3     65.2
```

The names are in column A, the Week values are in Row 1. (So A1 is blank, B1 = `Week 1`, and A2 = `Melissa`.)

I'm trying to build a formula that looks at all the values in a known range (in this example, B2:C5), chooses the highest value of the bunch (here, `122.5`) and returns the name of the person from Column A that got that value. If I use this formula, it works for the values in range B2:B5:

```
=INDEX(A2:A5,MATCH(MAX(B2:B5),B2:B5,0))
```

That returns `Melissa` but if I expand the range to include more than just column B's values, I get an `#N/A` returned:

```
=INDEX(A2:A5,MATCH(MAX(B2:C5),B2:C5,0))
```

The weird part (to my simple brain) is that the MATCH portion of the formula works fine, if I just put in this formula, it returns the highest value of `122.5` from C3:

```
=MAX(B2:C5,B2:C5,0)
```

So clearly something it going wrong when I'm using either the MATCH or INDEX commands.

Hopefully this makes sense and someone can point out my error?

Comment: I'm thinking of how to solve it, but the crux I believe is that `Match()` can only work over one column at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=INDEX(A:A,MAX((B2:C5=MAX(B2:C5))*ROW(B2:C5)))
```

> This is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Note: Match can only search one vector at a time. It can be one row or one column or one array. It cannot be two or more rows or columns or a 2D array.

Comment: That works for my example, thank you Excel Hero! I will mark this as a solution.
And thanks for the explanation about Match, good to know.

Comment: Hey, a follow-up question if I may: I decided I also want to calculate the MIN value for my range (which in my actual spreadsheet is B2:Q11). I changed the formula to use MIN instead, but because not all weeks are filled yet, it's returning the wrong value, as I'm guessing it sees those empty squares as zeroes. Here's my formula; can it be fixed to ignore zero/null values?  

`=INDEX(A:A,MIN((D2:S11=MIN(D2:S11))*ROW(D2:S11)))`
  
Thanks again!
Mike

Comment: I can give you the solution for the minimum, but can you please ask a new question for that? You can reference this question in that one to make it easier.

Comment: I have the solution ready. Please let me know when you have posted the new question.

Comment: Excel Hero - sorry I was away for a bit. Here's the new request:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33793498/formula-returning-column-a-value-for-row-containing-min-value-of-a-range

Answer (score 0):

Do it "twice"? Please try:

```
=INDEX(A2:A5,IFERROR(MATCH(MAX(B2:C5),B2:B5,0),MATCH(MAX(B2:C5),C2:C5,0)))
```

If you are going to have up to 52/53 weeks to cope with I'd suggest instead inserting a helper column with the MAX for each row. Make that an new (inserted) ColumnA (say `=MAX(C2:BC2)` etc.) and a simple VLOOKUP should serve, say:

```
=VLOOKUP(MAX(A:A),A:B,2,0)
```

Comment: This formula length will balloon as additional columns are considered.

Comment: I knew I could make a new column with the MAX for each user, then do a MAX function on that column, but I like to learn how to do it the cleanest way :)
Thank you all!