# Formula returning Column A value for row containing MIN value of a range

Tags: excel, max, min

Assume I have the following table:

```
  A         B         C
1           Week 1    Week 2
2 Melissa   114.7     82.8
3 Mike      105.5     122.5
4 Andrew    102.3     87.5
5 Rich      105.3     65.2
```

The names are in column A, the Week values are in Row 1. (So A1 is blank, B1 = Week 1, and A2 = Melissa.)

I'm trying to build a formula that looks at all the values in a known range (in this example, B2:C5), chooses the lowest value of the bunch (here, 65.2) and returns the name of the person from Column A that got that value (Rich).

I got a similar question for the MAX answered by "Excel Hero" [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33639796/formula-returning-column-a-value-for-row-containing-max-value-of-a-range), but it doesn't work the same if I just change MAX to MIN because there are some blank cells in the range, and those get selected.

Hopefully this makes sense and someone can help me? Thanks!

Mike

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
=INDEX(A:A,MAX((B2:C5=(MIN(IF(B2:C5>0,B2:C5,9E+99))))*ROW(B2:C5)))
```

> This is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.